# Running average of Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

#### Question :

> Let us define the cumulative sum (Brownian motion):
>   $$x_k = \sum_{i=1}^k y_i$$
>   and the running average :
>   $$ \overline{x_k} =\frac{1}{W}\sum_{i=k-W+1}^k x_i$$ for $ k>W $, $W$ is a positive integer.
>   Knowing that $ y_i \equiv \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ (at convenience $\mu=0$) and independent; what is the variance of $(\overline{x_{k+2K}}-\overline{x_{k+K}})-(\overline{x_{k+K}}-\overline{x_{k}})$ ?
>   $$ Var\left((\overline{x_{k+2K}}-\overline{x_{k+K}})-(\overline{x_{k+K}}-\overline{x_{k}})\right)$$
>   $K$ is a positive integer (at convenience over $W$).

This variance is inspired from Allan Variance. It's more efficient in the sens no preliminary calculation of $\mu$ is needed.

#### Attempt :

I was successful on calculating $Var\left(\overline{x_{k+K}}-\overline{x_{k}}\right)$ for $\mu=0$ and $W<K$.

$$ \overline{x_k} =\frac{1}{W}\sum_{i=k-W+1}^k \sum_{j=1}^i y_j$$

$$=\frac{1}{W}\left(W\sum_{i=1}^{k-W+1} y_i + \sum_{i=1}^{W-1} iy_{k-i+1}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{W}\left(W\sum_{i=1}^{k-W+1} y_i + \sum_{i=k-W+2}^{k} (k-i+1)y_{i}\right)\tag{1}$$

So:
$$ \overline{x_{k+K}}- \overline{x_k}=\frac{1}{W}\left(W\sum_{i=1}^{k+K-W+1} y_i + \sum_{i=k+K-W+2}^{k+K} (k+K-i+1)y_{i}-W\sum_{i=1}^{k-W+1} y_i - \sum_{i=k-W+2}^{k} (k-i+1)y_{i}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{W}\left(\sum_{i=k-W+2}^{k} (W-(k-i+1))y_i + \sum_{i=k+1}^{k+K-W+1} Wy_{i}+\sum_{i=k+K-W+2}^{k+K} (k+K-i+1)y_i \right)\tag{2}$$

Since the sums don't overlap anymore and $y_i$ are independent, we can calculate the variance of each terms. The variance of the sum is the sum of the variance for independent variables:

$$Var\left(\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+K-W+1} Wy_{i}\right)=(K-W+1)W^2\sigma^2$$
$$Var\left(\sum_{i=k-W+2}^{k} (W-(k-i+1))y_i\right)=\sigma^2\sum_{i=k-W+2}^{k} (W-(k-i+1))^2$$
$$=\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^{W-1} i^2=\sigma^2\frac{W(W-1)(2W-1)}{6}\tag{3}$$
$$Var\left(\sum_{i=k+K-W+2}^{k+K} (k+K-j+1)y_i \right)=\sigma^2\sum_{i=k+K-W+2}^{k+K} (k+K-j+1)^2$$
$$=\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^{W-1} i^2=\sigma^2\frac{W(W-1)(2W-1)}{6}$$

So we have for the sum of the three terms:
$$Var\left(\overline{x_{k+K}}-\overline{x_{k}}\right) = \frac{\sigma^2}{W^2}\left(\frac{W(W-1)(2W-1)}{3}+(K-W+1)W^2\right)$$
$$=K\sigma^2\left(1+\frac{1}{3K}\left(\frac{1}{W}-W\right)\right)\tag{4}$$

I checked this solution and it works; in the graph at the end, the blue line overlaps the blue dots. And we can see it is consistent since when $W=1$, the result is just $K\sigma^2$ and when $K$ is large, the bias $\frac{1}{3K}\left(\frac{1}{W}-W\right)$ becomes negligible.

But I didn't succeed in applying this method for the calculation of $ Var\left((\overline{x_{k+2K}}-\overline{x_{k+K}})-(\overline{x_{k+K}}-\overline{x_{k}})\right)$.

Since $({x_{k+2K}}-{x_{k+K}}) $ has a mean value of $K\mu$ and $-({x_{k+K}}-{x_{k}})$ a mean value of $-K\mu$ then I  figured that $\left(({x_{k+2K}}-{x_{k+K}})-({x_{k+K}}-{x_{k}})\right)$ has a mean value of $0$. The mean  value of $\left((\overline{x_{k+2K}}-\overline{x_{k+K}})-(\overline{x_{k+K}}-\overline{x_{k}})\right)$ should be pretty much the same : $0$. With this argument, I considered I could just take $\mu=0$ for this calculation. From the result (1) and with $W<K$:

$$(\overline{x_{k+2K}}-\overline{x_{k+K}})-(\overline{x_{k+K}}-\overline{x_{k}}) =\overline{x_{k+2K}}-2\overline{x_{k+K}}+\overline{x_{k}}
=\frac{1}{W}\left(W\sum_{i=1}^{k+2K-W+1} y_i+\sum_{i=k+2K-W+2}^{k+2K} (k+2K-i+1)y_i-2W\sum_{i=1}^{k+K-W+1} y_i-2\sum_{i=k+K-W+2}^{k+K} (k+K-i+1)y_i +W\sum_{i=1}^{k-W+1} y_i+\sum_{i=k-W+2}^{k} (k-i+1)y_i\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{W}\left(\sum_{i=k-W+2}^{k} ((k-i+1)-W)y_i-\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+K-W+1} Wy_i+ \sum_{i=k+K-W+2}^{k+K} (W-2(k+K-i+1))y_i+\sum_{i=k+K+1}^{k+2K-W+1} Wy_i+\sum_{i=k+2K-W+2}^{k+2K} (k+2K-i+1)y_i\right)$$$$\tag{5}$$

With this modification the sum don't overlap anymore and the variance of the sum is the sum of the variance. Lets compute the variance of each term :

$$ Var\left(\sum_{i=k-W+2}^{k} ((k-i+1)-W)y_i\right)=\sigma^2\sum_{i=k-W+2}^{k} ((k-i+1)-W)^2=\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^{W-1} i^2=\sigma^2\frac{W(W-1)(2W-1)}{6}$$
$$ Var\left(\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+K-W+1} Wy_i\right)=\sigma^2(K-W+1)W^2 $$
$$ Var\left(\sum_{i=k+K-W+2}^{k+K} (W-2(k+K-i+1))y_i\right) = \sigma^2\sum_{i=k+K-W+2}^{k+K} (W-2(k+K-i+1))^2 = \sigma^2\sum_{i=-W+2}^{W-2} i^2= 2\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^{W-2} i^2=\sigma^2\frac{(W-2)(W-1)(2W-3)}{3}$$
$$Var\left(\sum_{i=k+K+1}^{k+2K-W+1} Wy_i\right)=\sigma^2(K-W+1)W^2\tag{6}$$
$$ Var\left(\sum_{i=k+2K-W+2}^{k+2K} (k+2K-i+1)y_i\right)=\sigma^2\sum_{i=k+2K-W+2}^{k+2K} (k+2K-i+1)^2=\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^{W-1} i^2=\sigma^2\frac{W(W-1)(2W-1)}{6}$$

So the sum of these 5 terms makes :
$$Var(\overline{x_{k+2K}}-2\overline{x_{k+K}}+\overline{x_{k}})=\frac{1}{W^2}\left(\sigma^2\frac{W(W-1)(2W-1)}{3}+2\sigma^2(K-W+1)W^2+\sigma^2\frac{(W-2)(W-1)(2W-3)}{3}\right)$$
$$=2K\sigma^2\left(1-\frac{1}{K}\left(1-\frac{7}{3W}+\frac{W}{3}+\frac{1}{W^2}\right)\right)\tag{7}$$
But I checked this formula with statistical test and it doesn't fit (green line doesn't overlap the green dots).

[image: Statistical test for variance formula]

The Matlab code for this verification is available [here](http://www.lirmm.fr/~david-grig/VarianceFormulaVerification.m). Thank you for any help, it would be absolutely great.

Comment: Thank you for your interest for this question.
Yes, you are right. (2) is false for the cases where W>K. I am most interested in the cases where W<K. Although it would be neat to have a demonstration for the general case. I'll edit the attempt to take your remark in account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error before formula $(6)$ the correct calculation is
$$
Var\left(\sum_{i=k+K-W+2}^{k+K} (W-2(k+K-i+1))y_i\right) = \sigma^2\sum_{i=k+K-W+2}^{k+K} (W-2(k+K-i+1))^2 = \sigma^2\sum_{i=-W+2}^0(W+2i-2)^2=\sigma^2\frac{W(W-1)(W-2)}{3} 
$$

Comment: Thank you so much ! That's awesome !